# Bootstrap datepicker should always show current month page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
}).on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $('#datetimepicker1').val("");
    $('#sDate1').text($('#datetimepicker1').data('date'));
    $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('hide');
});
```

I am using the above code. If I click the `datepicker`, it shows the current month(nov) and if we select a date from next month(dec), when I click for the second time it is showing the next month page.

The requirement is it should show current month (i.e November now) whenever I click on `datepicker`. I have tried many things and I'm fed up with this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: try `minDate : Date.now()` I am 99% sure this is not going to work but give it a try

Comment: Can you share the plugin documentation site? Also I don't think you can achieve whatever you are trying straight out of the box..

Comment: The 'when I click for the second time' doesn't mean with the date still selected, does it? Because of course the selected date is displayed when you open the datepicker after first selecting a value. 

You could try calling setDate (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

Comment: @RickvandenBosch he wants the date to be selected also when he opens the calendar should show current month no matter which date is selected..

Comment: yes exactly @Reddy

Comment: sorry , minDate is not working @Dherya

Comment: @Reddy That's another way of putting what I said/asked :p My first question would be: _why?

Comment: @RickvandenBosch I know.. Just gave you an answer to your question

Comment: I am using datepicker which is in the following link @Reddy https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: @SuryaBadrinath No thats not the one you are using. because there is no `autoclose` & `todayHighlight` in it and you are using it in your code.. But this one has https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#todayhighlight can you confirm

Comment: @SuryaBadrinath gave you my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/wn8oo7x1/4/)**

As I told there is no straight forward approach as per my knowledge, Also I went through the complete plugin documentation.

This is a work around that does what you need.

Make these changes to your existing scripts

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  todayBtn: true,   // add this option.
});
```

The **[todayBtn](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#todaybtn)** is used to render a button on the bottom of the calendar which on click will take you to the current Date view.

So lets take advantage of this feature. Lets add this button and trigger it to click programatically when ever we open the calendar. To do so add this code.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').on('click',function(){
 $(this).siblings('.datepicker').find('.datepicker-days tfoot .today').trigger('click');
});
```

This will make sure the current date view is shown every time you open the calendar.

Now this will leave us with the button on the calendar named "Today". If you dont want this button simply hide it using css.

```
.datepicker-days tfoot .today {
  display: none !important; // !important required to override the plugin inline style
}
```

Comment: Good you eventually hacked it :)

Comment: @Dherya thanks... hack sounds much better than work around :p

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact widget you're using this might vary, but using defaultViewDate (or defaultDate) looks like it will fit your needs (although the *initially* kind of makes me think it won't work...):

> Date to view when initially opening the calendar. The internal value of the date remains today as default, but when the datepicker is first opened the calendar will open to defaultViewDate rather than today. If this option is not used, “today” remains the default view date

Comment: I have already tried defaultViewDate and defaultDate. Its  not working :-(

Answer (score 0):

This may help..

```js
$('#sandbox-container input').on('click', function(e){
 var setDate = new Date();
 $(this).datepicker('setDate', setDate);
})
```

Comment: You want to set focus on the current month only. that is what you need?

Comment: The OP wants to be able to select date anywhere on the calendar but when he opens the calendar next time it shouldn't show the selected date month.. It should always show the current month ..

Answer (score 0):

Need to use below concept to open the datepicker with selected date

```
var selectedDate = new Date();
$('#txtWQApprovalDate').datepicker('setDate',selectedDate).datepicker('fill');
```